# Remove an item based on itemID from a foreach loop

Tags: php

I am trying to hide/remove an item from a loop if an item id is present. I have manged to remove the item id of a product based on the id but how do i go about removing the actual item itself.

should be:

```
  foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {

      if ($item->itemId == 12345){
        continue;
        }

  }
```

Comment: From where you want to remove .. database or file ?

Comment: If an item id is unwanted, you want to skip the loop to the next occurence ?

Comment: Don't you want to unset '$resp->searchResult->item'(id=12345) instead of $item?

Comment: i want the $item removed from the api output if the itemID is present

Comment: Something like this `unset($resp->searchResult->item->itemId);` ?

Comment: if you want to just inset it in the foreach loop then you need the `reference` and unset that. i.e. `foreach($resp->searchResult->item as &$item) { ... unset($item) ... };`. The `foreach` loop is ok with this. Note the `as &$item` rather than `as $item`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you just don't want some items to be outputed

In your loop you should use the **continue** statement which is used to skip the rest of the current loop

> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Considering you have an array with the ids to exclude from your loop you could do like this :

```
<?php
$idsToExclude = [1234,1333,1444];

foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->itemId, $idsToExclude) {
        continue;
    }

    // Here you can use $item
    ....
}
```

This way you don't loop through your unwanted items

If you don't want to use an array and you only have one id to dismiss, you could just do like this :

```
<?php
foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
    if ($item->itemId == 1234) {
        continue;
    }

    // Here you can use $item
    ....
}
```

Or in your API call, you could as well add a parameter that indicate you wan't to exclude some results or include only some specifics items.

Comment: I don't have an array of the ids they are outputted during the api call. I wan to add a single itemID and it found not display that item in the output.

Comment: In that case you add your ID in the $idsToExclude. If I understand, you want to exclude an item from the loop and you know its ID right ?

Comment: Then you can use my code and just put your id in the array :
$idsToExclude = [1234]; or if you are sure that you won't need to forbid another id, you just can do if ($item->itemId == 1234) continue;

Comment: That's what i did initially but when i then try to unset($item) it does nothing.

Comment: Don't unset item, just use "continue;" to go to the next occurence of your loop, like in my example

Comment: That has now stopped the output of the call for some reason.

Comment: what does your loop look like ?

Comment: Just included the complete loop to the original question.

Comment: So now you just want to delete the item from the database ??

Comment: In your loop use == instead of =

Comment: if ($item->itemId == 160951771583){

Comment: just not show the item would be fine, don't need to delete it.